# WHERE Clause not working in StandardSetController extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Master-Detail relationship of `PP_Deals__c` (Master) and `Traches__c` (Detail).  I've created a VF to display two blocks of records and associated detail records.  One block showing deals with high chance of occurring and other block with deals with smaller chance.  I'm trying to accomplish this using an extension controller.  I'm facing two problems.

1. I can see that my extension controller constructor "extCon" is executed, but the list is not getting filtered as suggested by the WHERE clause.  I'm seeing all records.
2. How to accomplish getting two different lists using same controller?

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="PP_Deals__c" recordSetVar="deals" extensions="extCon">

    <font size="5" color="blue"> <b> Private Placement - Active Deal Log1 </b> </font>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Higher Chance">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! deals }" var="ds">
            <apex:column value="{! ds.Issuer__c }"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Bids Due" value="{! ds.Circle_Due_Date__c }"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Maturities">           
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ds.Tranches__r}" var="val">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Tenor" value="{! val.name }"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Lower Chance">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! deals }" var="ds">
            <apex:column value="{! ds.Issuer__c }"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Bids Due" value="{! ds.Circle_Due_Date__c }"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Maturities">           
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ds.Tranches__r}" var="val">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Tenor" value="{! val.name }"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public class extCon
{
    private final PP_Deals__c deal;

    public extCon(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) { 
               controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM PP_Deals__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thanks Santanu and Sabastian for a detailed explanation and code recommendation.  After making the change, I received following error when I tried to load the page "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: PP_Deals__c.Tranches__r".   Any recommendations on retrieving "Tranche__r" detail records??

Comment: You need to add all the fields in SOQL SELECT statement

Comment: Never mind, I got it working by adding an inner select to get "Tranche__r".  Thanks for the support.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it serves your purpose,  so that others may find this useful

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario, you are trying to display the based on filtered list. So, here `recordsetvar` is not needed.

You need to explicitly assign values of `controller.getRecords()` to the `deals`

```
public class extCon
{
    private final PP_Deals__c deal;
    public List<PP_Deals__c>deals {get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller {get;set;}  

    public extCon(ApexPages.StandardController contr) { 
         controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM PP_Deals__c WHERE Status__c = 'Active']));
         deals = controller.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Visualforce

Make it standardController with extensions.

```
<apex:page standardController="PP_Deals__c" extensions="extCon">
```

You can also refer my blog [Custom Controller Pagination - easiest way](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/03/custom-controller-pagination-easiest-way.html) for this kind of logic.

Comment: Santanu, that code is going to conflict with the `recordSetVar`

Comment: yes, I know, basically, the way it has coded recordsetvar will not work. OP is filtering the data, before showing to VFP and I have proceed this kind of logic

Comment: Agreed. I would suggest explaining that in your answer, perhaps even suggesting removing his standardSetController constructor (He needs two SSCs)

Comment: Updated my answer,  let me know if this solution works